# Apollo GraphQL Server - Multiple queries from the same single request returns only only error despite all the queries returns errors

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

We are making a GraphQL request with multiple different queries (query1 and query2) in it. Both of these queries return an error(NOT_FOUND_ERROR) from our business logic and we are expecting a response with 2 errors in it. But we are getting a response with only one error. Why are we not getting multiple errors in the response?

E.g.
**Query**

```
query {
    query1 {
         id
    }
    query2 {
         id
    }
}
```

**Expected Response (2 Errors)**

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "NOT_FOUND_ERROR",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 5
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "device"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "NOT_FOUND_ERROR"
            }
        },
        {
            "message": "NOT_FOUND_ERROR",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 5
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "device"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "NOT_FOUND_ERROR"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": null
}
```

**Current Response (1 Error)**

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "NOT_FOUND_ERROR",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 5
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "device"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "NOT_FOUND_ERROR"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": null
}
```

We are getting multiple errors as expected when the request has invalid queries.
E.g.
**Query**

```
query {
    invalid_query1 {
         id
    }
    invalid_query2 {
         id
    }
}
```

How can I get multiple custom errors from our business logic when using multiple queries in the same request?

Version: apollo-server-express(2.15.1)

Thank you

Comment: resolver code returning error?

Comment: Yes @xadm. I am returning an error from the resolver.

Comment: details.... how?

Comment: I have a custom error class which extends ApolloError. Basically I am throwing the error from the resolver using throw keyword.

Comment: how raw network response looks like? ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56089623/6124657 ?

Comment: I am testing the APIs using Postman and I have posted the API response in the question.

Comment: prepare minimal [example] /repo to allow recreate this possibly wrong behaviour and post an issue on github?